# What is the difference between `$( ... )` and `( ... )`?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What is the difference between `$( ... )` and `( ... )` and perhaps `.`  (`source`)?

---

At the very beginning of writing shell scripts I learned `$( ... )` is appropriate if i want to use the output of a command, e.g. for a variable:

```
size=$( wc -c < /path/to/file )
```

Then I figured out that I can use `( ... )` if I want a command to be executed (in a sub-shell), wait for it to exit and work with its output file, like:

```
( echo -e "a lot of data, if everything worked... ;-)" > /path/to/file )
```

Interestingly, it also works with `$( ... )`, but gives the somehow cryptic error message `scriptname: line 1: : Command not found.`:

```
$( echo -e "a lot of data, if everything worked... ;-)" > /path/to/file )
```

Why does `$( ... )` not work flawlessly for both use cases? Considering the error message, I guess the reason is something like: `$( ... )` "forces even an empty output at the shell" although there is none, whereas `( ... )` just executes the command and does not care about the output. Is that right?

---

I know there is also `.`  (with its alias `source`) to execute a command in the current shell, which seems to be more similar to `$( ... )`, concerning the function.

Or are there more differences between `.`  and `( ... )` than just executing the command in the current or a sub-shell that I'm not aware of?

Comment: yes, i know... i used [tag:bash] and [tag:sh] as tags. this is because i currently use bash, but want to get my scripts as much POSIX compliant as possible! **||**
...so taking care of differences between those two (if there are any?), would be the icing on the cake.

Comment: BTW, echo -e is not defined by POSIX.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski: i knew this would get mentioned! :-D **||** fortunately it seems the ` -e` gets just ignored and produces no error, so it kind of "works" for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merely running commands, in a subshell or not, does not involve any interaction with the shell itself after it executes those commands.

```sh
$ echo echo poo
echo poo
```

By contrast, a command substitution is evaluated by the shell after it finishes:

```sh
$ $(echo echo poo)
poo

$ var=$(echo echo poo)

$ echo "$var"
echo poo

$ $(echo "$var")   # expands to the first line (but is unnecessarily redundant)
poo

$ $var             # more succinct version of the previous line
poo
```

Of course, if you redirect the output of the command substitution, the shell ends up evaluating an empty string.

The `.` command (or, in Bash and some other non-POSIX shells, its synonym `source`) evaluates a sequence of commands in a file. This is in some sense vaguely similar to a command substitution, but the latter lets you capture and manipulate the result of the evaluation (and in some sense the whole *purpose* of the shell is to evaluate expressions).

A command substitution can really be used to evaluate an expression anywhere, whereas `.` or a subshell can only be used where the shell accepts a command. Look at these gymnastics:

```sh
$ $(echo e)$(echo c)$(echo h)$(echo o) "poo"
poo

$ echo p$(printf x | wc -l | tr -d ' ' | tr '1' 'o')o
poo

$ ech$(echo o poo)
poo
```

Like you discovered, a subshell can be useful when you want a group of commands to share some file discriptors;

```sh
( printf '%s\n' 'Subject: hello' \
    'MIME-version: 1.0' \
    'Content-type: application/octet-stream' \
    'Content-transfer-encoding: base64' \
    ''
  base64 binaryfile ) |
sendmail -oi you@example.net
```

or if you want to limit the scope of some environment changes;

```
for subdir in */; do
  ( cd "$subdir"
    condiments=$(cat spice.txt)
    export condiments
    make -s dinner )
# back in parent dir
# $condiments is back to its old value
# probably unset, and not exported
done
```

Comment: why `$(echo echo poo)` results in `poo`, but writing exact the same into a variable results in `echo poo` still confuses me a little bit. :-( **||** i guess the answer is, that it has to do with how often the command is executed... it seems to be a little bit like "nesting with `$` resp. <kdb>enter</kdb>".

Comment: Because the output from the command substitution is `echo poo` and it gets substituted in a place where the shell will evaluate that as a command. This is just like the other examples with `$(echo e)$(echo c)` etc. Similarly `$(echo nano fnord.txt)` will result in the output `nano fnord.txt` which then gets evaluated as a command, and `nano` is run on the file `fnord.txt`. (I don't particularly recommend `nano` but it's typically easier for beginners to get out of than a real editor.)

Comment: so to put it pretty simply, `$( ... )` and `( ... )` are more or less the same, but `$( ... )` gets executed immediately? :-/

Comment: No, not at all. Both are executed immediately. The crucial difference is that the output from `$( ... )` gets evaluated by the shell. That's literally the first few sentences of this answer.

Comment: I accepted your suggested edit but evaluating a variable as code is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

`$( cmd )` executes `cmd` and then tries to execute its output.  So

```
$( echo -e "a lot of data, if everything worked... ;-)" > /path/to/file )
```

executes a command that writes data to `/path/to/file` and produces no output. The shell takes that output (the empty string) and tries to execute it, producing the error message that you see.